# Calculating $ \lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{x\cdot\sin{x}}{|x|}) $

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

To solve $ \lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{x\cdot\sin{x}}{|x|}) $ I have separated the function in two limits:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{x\cdot\sin{x}}{|x|}) =
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{|x|} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \sin{x}
\end{align}

Now solving independently:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{|x|} =  \lim_{x \to 0} \text{sign}(x) \, \, \, \text{does not exist}
\end{align}

And:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \sin{x} = 0
\end{align}

I've checked graphically and I'm aware that the limit is $ 0 $, however, I'm not sure that multiplying "undefined" by $ 0 $ is something allowed.

Can I do this? If not, what could be another way of solving the limit?

**Edit:**

Just realized I can split the function in a different way, knowing that $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{|x|} = 1 $

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{x\cdot\sin{x}}{|x|}) =
\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{|x|\cdot\sin{x}}{x}) =
\lim_{x \to 0} |x| \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 0 \cdot 1 = 0
\end{align}

How about this second approach?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x \to a}(f \cdot g)=(\lim_{x \to a} f) \cdot (\lim_{x \to a}g)$ requires the existence of both limits on the right side which is not the case here. Instead you can say as $x \to 0^{+}$, then the function is $\sin x$ and as $x \to 0^{-}$, the function is $-\sin x$.

Comment: Why on the right side specifically? Shouldn't be, in general, the existence of both limits?

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0 \iff \lim_{x \to 0} \lvert f(x)\rvert = 0$$

Comment: We have that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{|x|} = \pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks, @user. Made a typo with the $ |x| $ in the denominator, should be just $ x $

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ x\cdot \sin x}{|x|} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ |x| \cdot \sin x}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} |x| \cdot \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 0\cdot 1 = 0.$$

Comment: Very clever method!

Comment: insane! wouldn't have thought!

Answer (score 6):

You can separate a limit into two only if both exist. Here as you point out, one of them does not, so this step is wrong.

You can say that $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ is bounded, $\sin(x)$ goes to $0$, so their multiplication goes to $0$ as well.

Alternatively, calculate $x\to 0^+$ and $x\to 0^-$ and see they are equal.

Answer (score 5):

Approach $0$ from the right:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x\sin{x}}{|x|}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x\sin{x}}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\sin x=0.$$

Then approach $0$ from the left:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{x\sin{x}}{|x|}=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{x\sin{x}}{-x}=\lim_{x \to 0^-}-\sin x=0.$$

Since $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x\sin{x}}{|x|}=0=\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{x\sin{x}}{|x|}$, the limit is zero.

Answer (score 4):

The important fact is that $\frac{x}{|x|}$ is bounded that is

$$-1\le\frac{x}{|x|}\le 1$$

therefore

$$0\le \left|\frac{x\cdot\sin{x}}{|x|}\right|\le|\sin x| \to 0$$

and we can conclude by squeeze theorem.

Alternatively we can use that

$$\frac{|\sin{x}|}{|x|} \to 1$$

and therefore

$$0\le \left|\frac{x\cdot\sin{x}}{|x|}\right|=|x|\frac{|\sin{x}|}{|x|} \to 0\cdot 1=0$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew about the approach using the squeeze theorem but I'm afraid I don't understand how to use in this context. I'm aware that the signum function is bounded between -1 and 1, and sin(x) is also bounded in the same way.

With that information, how can I discover that my original function is between them?

Comment: @Jon We know that $x/|x|$ is bounded whereas $\sin x \to 0$, for that reason the product goes to zero. To formalize that we invoque squeeze theorem but it is a very intuitive fact.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x\sin(x)}{\left| x\right|}$. If $x$ approaches $0$ from the right, $x>0$, so $\left| x\right| = x$. Hence, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$$$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x}$$$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\sin(x)$$$$=0.$$ Because $f(x)=f(-x)$, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=0.$$ Therefore, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0.$